# Usually, main results are called theorems, while smaller results are called propositions. Is there a name for super-immediate results?

Tags: terminology, proof-writing

In mathematical papers, main results are called theorems, while less central results are called propositions. But sometimes, there is a result that is so immediate, it doesn't even deserve to be called a proposition; but nonetheless, you want to state it, just for emphasis. Consider the following example.

**Definition**. Write $x \sim y$ iff $x \leq y$ and $y \leq x$.

**Proposition**. If $x \sim y$, then $x \leq y$.

In my opinion, the word 'proposition' is far too strong for these kind of results. 'Proposition' suggests an insight, however small, but there is no insight here; the result is just there for emphasis.

Is there a traditional name for these kinds of super-immediate results? I'm tempted to call it a 'corollary', but that term is usually reserved for something that follows immediately from a theorem (proposition etc.), rather than a definition.

Comment: observation, remark?

Comment: I'd use "Observation" or even "Remark."

Comment: Corollary is often used for immediate consequences of a theorem.

Comment: That particular case is probably not worth writing down. Can you come up with a more realistic example? "Note that" or "In particular" come to mind. I also prefer the term "lemma" to "proposition" myself, if its purpose is to prove a theorem. I'd reserve "proposition" for something more like a minor theorem.

Comment: @dfeuer, for a more realistic example: Definition. An ordinal number is a hereditarily transitive set. Remark. Every natural number is an ordinal number.

Comment: Once in a while, “lemma” is the appropriate word. Depends on context, of course, but I am sure you can figure that out.

Comment: I’ve been using “Observation” for statements whose proof should be perfectly clear and should not present any difficulty to the reader. I’ve even numbered them like Propositions. Referees have occasionally raised an eyebrow, but have not insisted on a change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing changes over the decades. If I'm reading something, I like to have definitions numbered and obvious. Plenty of important books and papers gve definitions in the middle of a sentence, with the new term or phrase in italics. This is fine if you really are reading the thing word for word, but harder to follow if skipping around.

At the other end, I do not always give a heading or name for every corollary or intermediate result. Having too few numbered and named ("Theorem") items is one way to be obscure, another way is to name and number every other line, so that the important stuff does not stand out.

Now that i think of it, I am more likely than most authors to put little cautionary notes, after a definition especially. There are always places where you write something which is unambiguous, but where a reader without your experience might misinterpret. So I often say "Note that property W does not really imply property X." Sometimes co-authors have made me remove such "notes," as too much coddling of the reader. As an example, if using the Legendre/Jacobi symbol and saying "so that $(n|p) = -1,$" I am likely to also say "note that this requires that $p$ not divide $n.$"

So, as the others are saying, a paragraph of remarks, possibly without the heading "Remark," is a good middle ground.

Comment: I read part of a text on set theory that would sometimes go so far as to introduce *axioms* without a heading.

Comment: @dfeuer, that seems surprising, given that texts on set theory generally err on the side of formality. Which book was it?

Comment: @user18921: The book I'm thinking of is Smullyan and Fitting, but I could be mis-remembering.